# Add sticky based on page position not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add class, based on the position and scrolling of the user.
I want to use this for a submenu, that should become sticky when the user scrolls over it.

Beside that is should add the class "active" to the menu item, when the section from the page is displayed.

For some reason it does not work.

What am I missing?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d737mt5g/2/

jQuery:

```
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.menu-header-product'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 88) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
$j(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $j('.content'),
      scroll = $j(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset=jQuery("#productnav").offset();    
  if (scroll >= elementOffset.top - 88) sticky.addClass('sticky');
  else sticky.removeClass('sticky');
});
    $j(document).ready(function () {
        $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

        $j('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $j(document).off("scroll");

            $j('a').each(function () {
                $j(this).removeClass('active');
            })
            $j(this).addClass('active');

            var target = this.hash;
            $jtarget = $j(target);
            $j('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $jtarget.offset().top - 88 /**just subtract the height of the fixed html part */
             }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                window.location.hash = target;
                $j(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
            });
        });
    });

function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $j(document).scrollTop();
        $j('nav a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $j(this);
            var refElement = $j(currentLink.attr("href"));
            if (refElement.position().top - 88 <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top - 125 + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $j('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            }
            else{
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: didn't you post this question yesterday?  try pressing f12 and have a look at the console, I get an error in your fiddle cannot read top of undefined

Comment: @Pete Thanks for your reply. Yes I did, but I removed the question by accident.

Comment: Could you show a css?